# iOS, unrecognized selector sent to instance?

Tags: ios, iphone, xib, ibaction

I got a mainscreen with a imported custom actionBar. I created this actionBar in a separate .xib file, with a .m and .h file.

I do some graphic setup in my actionBar.m's `viewDidLoad` like `backgroundColor` and some other stuff.

I also got a button on this `actionBar` i linked the way i usually link buttons, with a `IBAction`.

I load my actionBar into my mainscreen like this:

```
ActionBarWithLogoff *actionBar = [[ActionBarWithLogoff alloc] initWithNibName:@"ActionBarWithLogoff" bundle:nil];
[topBar addSubview:actionBar.view];
[actionBar release];
```

My actionBar.h:

```
- (IBAction)ActionBarLogoff:(id)sender;
```

My actionBars.m's method:

```
-(void) ActionBarLogoff:(UIButton *)sender
{
NSLog(@"!!!!!!!!!!ActionBarLogoff");
}
```

This is were my error steels the picture, when i click the button i get the following error:

> 2014-01-27 13:52:21.856 GB_Mobil_DK[2954:60b] -[__NSArrayM
>   ActionBarLogoff:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1656d880
>   2014-01-27 13:52:21.858 GB_Mobil_DK[2954:60b] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSArrayM ActionBarLogoff:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x1656d880'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x2f94be83 0x39ca86c7 0x2f94f7b7 0x2f94e0af 0x2f89cdc8 0x32104da3 0x32104d3f 0x32104d13 0x320f0743
>   0x3210475b 0x32104425 0x320ff451 0x320d4d79 0x320d3569 0x2f916f1f
>   0x2f9163e7 0x2f914bd7 0x2f87f471 0x2f87f253 0x345b92eb 0x32134845
>   0x97985 0x3a1a1ab7) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException

Anyone able to tell me why? and most importantly able to help me solve this problem^^?

Comment: Show the real error message.

Comment: CHECK BUTTON'S OUTLET METHOD NAME AND REAL METHOD NAME. MAY BE BOTH ARE DIFFERENT.

Comment: are you using ARC....

Comment: Go to Breakpoint Navigator, at the bottom of panel click 'plus' sign - Add Exception Breakpoint... - Add. Then repeat all the steps and notice we in your code the error arises.

Comment: I'm using MRC, check post for updated full error message

Comment: post your button selector code..

Comment: done, updated post with the code for my UIButton

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are releasing the `actionBar` instance and just retaining its `view`. If `actionBar` instance is responder to button action, then button click message is getting sent to deleted instance. You should retain the `actionBar` instance. One way to do this is making it an ivar or a `retain` property.

Also looks like you are creating a `UIViewController` for a custom view. Instead you can create just a custom `UIView` with its XIB.

EDIT

Declare retain property,

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) ActionBarWithLogoff *actionBar;
```

OR

Simply declare as ivar,

```
@interface YourViewController: UIViewController {
    ActionBarWithLogoff *actionBar;
}
```

And in `dealloc` method,

```
-(void) dealloc {
    //...

    [actionBar release];

    //...
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: so i should stop calling [actionBar release]? or do i need to change that to something ells to retain it?

Comment: @user2408952 Yes you should not release it like you are doing now. Look at my updated answer for suggestion.

Comment: I got it working by changing release to retain. please reply back if this isn't the proper way of doing it. If it is, then thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @user2408952 No, that is not correct way. It will create memory leak. You should declare `actionBar` as `retain`-property in your class or as instance variable. Release it in `dealloc` method of class.