# I am getting this error when integrate Crashlytics frameworkd in my app '-[Digits start]: error

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

i am following from Fabric documentation but i did not install Digit Framework

i am getting this error when integrate Crashlytics  frameworkd in my app 
'-[Digits start]:'

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS, unrecognized selector sent to instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381641/ios-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Comment: hi karan ,
my question is different

Comment: you have edited... And I know you are getting Unrecognized selector sent. Which is common in IOS, since you are missing framework, or search path. please check twice.

Comment: If you have not used  Digits framework, then where is your [Digits start] lines of code ????

Comment: @VishalSonawane
i do not know why it comes
i am just add crashytics framework to my app

Comment: Check whether you have any files related to Digits framework. Also check if you have linked framework or not. Because its highly impossible that Xcode will show error about code which does not exists in your project.

Comment: please check Carshlytics framework integration is proper. OR please check if you are missing paths.

Comment: if know  proper  crashlyltics doc  send link

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/33669/overview-of-ios-crash-reporting-tools-part-1

And

http://try.crashlytics.com/sdk/